# HTML NFT (ERC721) Not displaying correctly from data url

Tags: erc-721, opensea

I've built and deployed an HTML nft (ERC721). I've passed a data url containing the base64 encoded html document to the animation_url parameter. This data url shows up correctly when I paste it into a browser window, but on opensea it's not showing correctly. The HTML skeleton is visible, but the embedded CSS and and JS scripts aren't running.

Here is a link to the nft: https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/0x564d6b3b4100e82a9feddace0450e2f2bc33a64f/0

Has anyone been able to successfully deploy an HTML nft using a data url for the animation_url parameter? I'm not sure why this isnt working right. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Opensea's Content Security Policy does not allow inline javascript. Try inspecting your "image display" on opensea with your browser dev tools and copy the src url of the respective iframe to a new tab. Inspect the page (that should still not run scripts) with your browser dev tools and see the red error messages: One of them should say

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'none'".
```

or similar. To go around this you would have to extract the javascript to a separate file. To my knowledge this is not possible for data urls. In case you found a way please let me know.

I checked for your case and you can also directly see it from the browser inspection view.
[image: CSP Violated]